# Matlab Network Average path length

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

I've created an Erdős random graph which is of the format  n by n symmetric matrix with the attribute sparse. I'm trying to work out the average path length using the following code:

```
% Compute average path length for a network - the average shortest path
% INPUTS: adjL - matrix of weights/distances between nodes
% OUTPUTS: average path length: the average of the shortest paths between every two edges
% Note: works for directed/undirected networks
% GB, December 8, 2005

function l = ave_path_length(adj)

n=size(adj,1);

dij = [];

for i=1:n; dij=[dij; simple_dijkstra(adj,i) ]; end

l = sum(sum(dij))/(n^2-n); % sum and average across everything but the diagonal
```

It uses Dijkstra algorithm in the following link:
http://strategic.mit.edu/docs/matlab_networks/simple_dijkstra.m

However, Matlab becomes busy and I don't get a result. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: busy means it is processing, if no error message is produced, you might want to wait for it. Or try to minimize the amount of data input to see if the output is correct before proceeding with whole portion of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are growing a matrix, in that `dij` starts off empty and is appended to with each loop, so its size is changing. In MATLAB, this can result in significant slowdowns in running time and in the worst cases, MATLAB will basically hang.

Presuming you know the final size of `dij` (from a cursory examination, I believe this should be `n x n`), you should preallocate. In this case, zeros would work:

```
dij = zeros(n);
for i=1:n
    dij(n,:) = simple_dijkstra(adj,i);
end
```

If you open your original code in the MATLAB editor, you will probably see a little orange underline under `dij` within the loop. This indicates a warning. Hover over it and you should get this warning:

> The variable 'dij' appears to change size on every loop iteration.
>   Consider preallocating for speed.

Even for the case where you're not 100% sure of the final size, it can be better to over-allocate to the maximum possible size, and then trim down the unused portion.